# Column exist but program don t see?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I created a 3 tables but in the last one shows errors

```
    CREATE TABLE Student
(
    St_Id char(7) PRIMARY KEY,
    St_Fname varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    St_Lname varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    St_DOB date
)



   CREATE TABLE Course
(
    Course_code char(5) PRIMARY KEY,
    Course_title varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    Course_credit INTEGER NOT NULL
)


CREATE TABLE Registration 
(
    Reg_no INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ,
    FOREIGN KEY (St_Id) REFERENCES Student(St_Id),
    FOREIGN KEY (Course_code) REFERENCES Course(Course_code),
    Mark_obtaines INTEGER
)
```

> and error is
>
> Execution finished with errors. Result: unknown column "St_Id" in
> foreign key definition At line 1: CREATE TABLE Registration  (    Reg_no
> INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ,  FOREIGN KEY (St_Id) REFERENCES
> Student(St_Id),

Answer (score 1):

In order to define a foreign key, you need to define the column first -- and the types need to match the type in the referenced table:

```
CREATE TABLE Registration  (
    Reg_no INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    St_Id CHAR(7),
    Course_Code CHAR(5),
    FOREIGN KEY (St_Id) REFERENCES Student(St_Id),
    FOREIGN KEY (Course_code) REFERENCES Course(Course_code),
    Mark_obtaines INTEGER
);
```

Then the `FOREIGN KEY` declaration provides more information about the column.